# Parallel test execution in Perl

Tags: perl, selenium, parallel-processing, automation

Does anyone have any idea about parallel execution of test cases in perl using selenium.

Is there any perl module similar to ParallelComputer in JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

[In your test files:](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium)

```
use Test::WWW::Selenium;
⋮
```

[Call the harness:](http://p3rl.org/prove)

```
prove --jobs 10
```

Comment: I had tried this. My Test Automation framework doesn't support this as the methods are called dynamically.