# Parallel test execution in Perl for Selenium Grid

Tags: perl, selenium, parallel-processing

I had a perl script which executes in Multiple browsers parallely. I need to set this script in `sub setup()` which continues execution . I face a problem as the setup () encounters the end of sub `}`

The code is as follows:

```
    my @browser = ('*firefox','*iexplore');
   my $i = @browser;  
$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($i);

    foreach $browser (@browser){

    $pid =  $pm->start and next;

    $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => $host , port => 4444, browser => $browser, browser_url => $url,);
    $sel->start();
    print("\n Execution : ".$browser."\n");
    $sel->open("/");


    $pm->finish();

    }
```

Comment: Also see previously: [Parallel test execution in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648020/parallel-test-execution-in-perl) – If you did not like the answer you got there, you should mention in the previous thread why it was not helpful or applicable or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use startup and shutdown methods . For reference check this.

[Passing Parameter to Test::Class Setup method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682276/passing-parameter-to-testclass-setup-method/10691516#10691516)

Answer (score 0):

So what does it take to run tests in parallel? Well all you need is a parallel test runner. Fortunately for us, Perl is the Swiss Army knife of the internet (and automation as well). For our implementation we'll be using one module and perl's fork().

The first module is available here: [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm)
The second comes with your Perl distribution

We'll be using File::Find::Rule to parse directories and create lists (arrays) of files in the process; and for managing our multiple tests running in parallel fork().

```
1:  #!C:/Perl64/bin/perl  
2:  use strict;  
3:  use warnings;  
4:  use File::Find::Rule;  
5:    
6:  my $start_dir = shift || 'C:\Tests\';  
7:  my $count = 0;  
8:    
9:  my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($start_dir);  
10:    
11:  my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()  
12:                ->name( '*.pl' ) # Get only perl files  
13:                ->in( $subdirs[0] );  
14:    
15:  foreach my $test (@files) {  
16:    my $pid = fork;  
17:    die "fork failed" unless defined $pid;  
18:      
19:    if ($pid == 0) { # We Got a Child  
20:      print "Executing Test: " . $test . " Sequence #: " . $count . "\n";  
21:      my $exit_code = system($test);  
22:      print "Done Executing Test: " . $test . " Sequence #: " . $count . "\n";  
23:      print "Exit Code: " . ($exit_code >> 8) . "\n";  
24:      exit ($exit_code >> 8);  
25:    }  
26:    $count++;    
27:  }  
28:  exit(0);
```

If you run the above script with two .pl files in the C:\Temp\ directory you get the following output:

```
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test1.pl Sequence #: 0  
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test2.pl Sequence #: 1  
 Done Executing Test: C:\Temp\test2.pl Sequence #: 1  
 Exit Code: 2  
 Done Executing Test: C:\Temp\test1.pl Sequence #: 0  
 Exit Code: 1
```

This is what the above script is doing:
1. You pass in a directory or it uses C:\Tests\ as the default
2. Create a list of subdirectories
3. Go into each directory and get a list of files
4. Fork each one of those files (making sure they exit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another quick tutorial on how to implement a parallel test runner (for Selenium or any other type of test).

First the code:

```
1:  #!C:/Perl64/bin/perl  
2:  use strict;  
3:  use warnings;  
4:  use File::Find::Rule;  
5:    
6:  my $start_dir = shift || 'C:\Tests';  
7:  my $count = 0;  
8:    
9:  my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in($start_dir);  
10:    
11:  my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()  
12:                ->name( '*.pl' ) # Only get perl files  
13:                ->in( $subdirs[0] );  
14:  foreach my $test (@files) {  
15:    system(1, $test);  
16:    print "Executing Test: " . $test . " Sequence #: " . $count . "\n";  
17:    print "My Father Is: " . $$ . "\n"; # process that started me  
18:    $count++;  
19:  }  
20:  exit(0);
```

The magic here is being performed by line 15. Using the perl function system in this special form we can force it to not wait for the process it is launching before continuing, effectively allowing us to spawn multiple tests at the [almost] same time.

From the Perl docs:

> ```
> system(1, @args)
>
> spawns an external process and immediately returns its process designator, without waiting for it to terminate.
> ```

The above script will output the following:

```
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test_template.pl Sequence #: 0  
 My Father Is: 8692  
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test_template2.pl Sequence #: 1  
 My Father Is: 8692  
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test_template3.pl Sequence #: 2  
 My Father Is: 8692  
 Executing Test: C:\Temp\test_template4.pl Sequence #: 3  
 My Father Is: 8692
```

The below image shows how, in my debugger, the test runner has stopped but the 4 spawned processes are still running (theoretically running automated tests) as indicated in my Windows Task Manager by the running perl.exe processes.

[image]

That's all it takes to launch multiple automated tests at the same time, using Perl's system function.