# Passing Parameter to Test::Class Setup method

Tags: perl, testing, automation

I need to invoke a browser in selenium dynamically.

To achieve this I need to send the browser name as parameter to the set-up or start-up methods in `Test::Class`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub startup : Test( startup ) {

    my ($self) = @_;
    my $arg = shift;

     $self->{browser_type} = $arg->{browser};

    -------------------------------#some other code for myself

    $self->{browser} =
        Test::WWW::Selenium->new(
            host        => $self->{host},
            port        => $self->{port},
            browser     => $self->{browser_type},
            browser_url => $self->{test_url},
    );
```

In my test script I need it to call using the following

```
my $t1 =  Test::Class::Selenium::TestCases->new(browser=>$browser,);
Test::Class->runtests($t1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to get a browser, then reuse it for some tests, then destroy it later?  So just use a  global to hold the browser you create.  For example:

```
my $browser = '';
sub b_connect : Test(startup) {
   $browser = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost",
                              port => 4444,
                              browser => "*iexplore",
                              browser_url => "http://www.google.com",
                            );
};

sub b_disconnect : Test(shutdown) {
  $browser->close()
};
```

Just use the $browser var in you tests.

Comment: No. I pass the browser list as an array and I get the startup executed for each and every browser i Passed as an argument