# Why does the Perl app 'prove' launch my scripts in parallel but not execute test cases within those scripts in parallel?

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl, testing, selenium

I've got a couple of `.t` files in a folder.  Each test script launches its own instance of Selenium and therefore opens its own browser.  These then pass their instructions to page objects in separate modules.  The page objects are where most of the test assertions occur, alas.

I run them in parallel using `prove -j2 testfolder`.  When I do this I see two browsers open, responding to the Selenium calls, but the test results and browser action indicate that the second script only goes as far as just before the first script's first call to `Test::More`, then it hangs until the first script has finished.

The page object model is a red herring.  I've tried just putting bare `pass()` calls at the top of each `.t` file and confirmed that the test case in the second script isn't tried until the entire first script is completed.

Each `testX.t` file ends up looking something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 40;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use MyPage::Object; # test execution module

my $sel = new Driver( 'browser_name' => $browser,'
                      'remote_server_addr' => $host,
                      'port' => "80", );

pass("Debug test case - let's see when this passes");

my $user = new MyPage::Object( text => "test string", sel => $sel);
$user->verify_text;
.
.
```

Here's what `Object.pm` looks like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WebElement qw(get_text);

package Object;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless { @_ }, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub verify_text {
    my ($self, $text_to_verify) = @_;
    my $webElement = $self->{sel}->find_element("//*$xpath") or warn $!; 
    my $returnedtext = get_text($webElement) or warn $!;
    Test::More::ok($returnedtext =~ /\Q$text_to_verify/, "text matches");
}

1;
```

Here's the output.  While the first test is running I see this:

```
===(       4;12   4/40  0/? )===========================================
```

The first pair of numbers and the left number in the second pair go up as the first script's test cases are verified.  After this, when the second script starts, the output changes to this:

```
testfolder\test2.t .. 4/35
```

With the left number increasing as test cases are executed.

Shouldn't running these in parallel cause the assertions in each of them to be run at the same time?  Is this unusual or is this how parallel jobs are supposed to work in `prove`?

I'm running this from the command line in 64-bit Windows 7, ActiveState Perl v5.16.1.  CPAN shows Prove is up to date (3.28).

Comment: Could you post a minimal demonstration of the problem, please?

Comment: @ikegami: How so?  Should I paste source code?

Comment: Parallel testing with `prove` usually works, at least on Unix systems. I suspect that it's the Selenium calls which maybe do some kind of locking, forcing all but the first job to wait.

Comment: We need more dummy `pass`es. Put some between your imports, by enclosing them with `BEGIN` blocks. Also, put one before you create a new `Driver` → `use Test::More ...; BEGIN{ pass "loaded T::M" }; use Selenium::Remote::Driver; BEGIN { pass "loaded Selenium" }; ...` or just use `BEGIN { use_ok ... }`. This information is needed to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I've added these as recommended.  It seems the results for the tests in `test2.t` are not being displayed (or even iterated in the counter) but they are being verified behind the scenes.  I can tell because `test2.t` is still able to blow by them and get a Selenium browser launched dutifully.  `test2.t` runs up until `test1.t` starts outputting results.  All these new tests pass eventually.

Comment: It also looked like `test2.t` got hung up on a Selenium execution that was not associated with test results, so it isn't specifically assertions which aren't firing in the second script.  It's just stopping wherever it is as soon as `test1.t` makes its first call to `Test::More` from within `MyPage::Object`.

Comment: Still hacking at this but I have come up with a lame workaround. I've written a batch script that does `start prove -v testfolder/test1.t` once for each test file.  Weak sauce, but it works for now.

Comment: And, hey!  It works fine on Linux!

Comment: @kyoob Then this is worth a bug report! Tools like these ought to work as documented regardless of platform.

Comment: FWIW I've now opened issue reports with the `App::Prove` and `Selenium::Remote::Driver` maintainers.  Here's hoping we can get this resolved. - https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=93788 - https://github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/issues/107

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround, though this isn't really a solution to the root issue.  I used a combo of [this solutions at the Sauce Labs blog](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/04/running-your-selenium-tests-in-parallel-perl/) and [Freddy Vega's solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681818/parallel-test-execution-in-perl-for-selenium-grid) to come up with this:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Thread::Pool::Simple;

my $count = 0;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
    ->name( '*.t' )
    ->in( 'C:\path\to\tests\' );

sub worker() {
    my $file = shift;
    system("prove $file");
    print "Executing Test: " . $file . "\n";
}

my $pool = Thread::Pool::Simple->new(
    min =>  5,
    max =>  25,
    do  =>  [\&worker],
);

foreach my $test (@files) {
    $pool->add($test);
    print "Added $test to pool..\n";
    $count++;
}
$pool->join();

exit(0);
```